# Additional Uncaught Exception?

Tags: database, entities

I updated some modules, and the site was working fine afterward; then, I made some changes to my .info file, uploaded, and suddenly I'm getting this error.

> Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.
>
> Original
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column "base.access_exposed" in "field list&": SELECT base.id AS id, base.name AS name, base.label AS label, base.plugin AS plugin, base.active AS active, base.weight AS weight, base.status AS status, base.dirty AS dirty, base.module AS module, base.access_exposed AS access_exposed, base.data AS data FROM {rules_config} base WHERE (base.plugin = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (base.active = :db_condition_placeholder_1) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => reaction rule [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 1 ) in EntityAPIController->query() (line 152 of /home/content/92/8292092/html/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.controller.inc).
>
> Additional
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column "base.access_exposed" in "field list&": SELECT base.id AS id, base.name AS name, base.label AS label, base.plugin AS plugin, base.active AS active, base.weight AS weight, base.status AS status, base.dirty AS dirty, base.module AS module, base.access_exposed AS access_exposed, base.data AS data FROM {rules_config} base WHERE (base.plugin = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (base.active = :db_condition_placeholder_1) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => reaction rule [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 1 ) in `EntityAPIController->query()` (line 152 of /home/content/92/8292092/html/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.controller.inc).

I do have a database backup that was made before updating the modules.

The error cites entity, but nothing has changed there since Drupal was installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you updated the modules manually, rather than using the Drupal UI system then you must run example.com/update.php on the URL.  It is likely that one of the modules you updated made changes to the database table system.  If you do not run update.php, then the modules may not have made the necessary table structure changes that match the code.

Answer (score 0):

Entity API is constantly evolving and still has backwards-incompatible changes with new releases.  Furthermore, the latest stable release is pretty old (5 months ago).

There's a good chance some of the modules you updated rely on an updated version of Entity API.

Try updating Entity API to the dev version and running update.php.

Comment: Thanks, while this issue was resolved after running update.php, updating entity sounds like a good idea anyway?

Comment: If it's working you shouldn't touch it! :)